# SMD identification - marked OULO

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, identification, surface-mount

[image]I have some SMDs from a board which I am not able to identify. On top of the ICs is the marking:

OULO- SOT 23-5 (I'm not sure if they are zero or O.)

In the picture U4 and U5 are the OULO component.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Is TI OPA336NA op-amp. Link to datasheet [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa336.pdf?ts=1605027824579&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DOPA336NA%252F250)
   [image: A36]

[eBay link](https://www.ebay.com/i/353153597542?chn=ps)

[image: ebay image]

2. Could be Torex XC6101F619XX, (XC61xxF6xxxx, XC61Xxxx19xx) with the last digit being the production code. Link [here](http://mpdf1.alldatasheet.com/mobile.jsp?pNo=194206&pMfg=TOREX&pName=XC6101F619&lang=en). You need to measure and/or photograph the location and trace some surrounding components to be sure.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you help me with the 2nd component

Comment: @AndreSmith You need to provide more information for that. Can you take a photo of it in circuit? I need to see the surrounding components and pinout.

Comment: Yes. I have edited the post and added the photo. Let me know if you need any more information

Comment: @AndreSmith Can't tell if it's U3 or U4 from the image. Can you follow the traces and make a mini-schematic of the connections and components connected to it?

Comment: I have added a hand drawn schematic. U4 and U5 are marked is OULO.

Comment: @AndreSmith Very good! But that's boarderline a wiring diagram :-).If you focus around U4 and/or U5 and name the pins 12345 as per SOT-23-5 naming convention, do you have anything which matches the XC6101F619XX datasheet? Especially Vcc and GND...